# Is there a cross-platform notepad?

Tags: android, notes

The useage of my PC would be so much easier if there was a way to copy and paste links, notes, scripts, etc to a notepad from my Android (Samsung phone) and open them on my PC with a simple click of an icon.
Is there a cross-platform notepad app for Linux/Ubuntu AND Android, please?

I searched Snap Store and the Ubuntu apps with no luck and Google gave me loads of false answers and wasted my time.

I'd go for "ease of access" over security (I'd rather not have to enter passwords every time I open it).
There is absolutely nothing personal on the PC, I'll just be sending instructions to myself as I'm only using it to learn more about computers.

Comment: I use `Google keep` for that purpose.

Comment: I use Evernote on Android and Windows, and NixNote2 on Ubuntu (NixNote2 is an unofficial Evernote client for Linux).

Comment: You don't really need a cross platform application to open and edit text-only documents on different devices. You just need an application on each platform that can read and write text-only documents.  Of course the documents need to be located in a place that is accessible to all of your devices like OwnCloud or some other cloud storage provider.

Comment: I use joplin with dropbox and KDEconnect with clipboard sharing.

Answer (score 2):

[Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/) is great open source, cross platform notes app for all major PC and mobile platforms. It supports markdown and tags.

It's also on the [snap store](https://snapcraft.io/joplin-desktop). The Joplin-Desktop by james-carroll is actively maintained probably the one you'd want. The snap store also has a command line variant. Outside of the snap store, it's on flathub, and as an AppImage from their website.

You can host your notes locally on your PC, your own Nextcloud instance, or through something like Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting question here would be : where should you put your note to be able to edit it from either your laptop or phone ?

I can imagine 2 different scenarios :

1. You keep your notes on a server, or a cloud, let's simply call it a "remote location". Then both your phone and computer connect to this remote location, not necessarily with the exact same application. You could go this way with [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) and [Nextcloud Notes](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/notes) for example, but also Google Keep, Evernote... I would nevertheless recommend to stick with an open file format such as simple txt or markdown to be sure that you'll find an app able to edit your notes.
2. You keep your notes on your phone, and you edit them directly on your phone from your computer. You could do this by wired connection, Bluetooth, or even wifi with [KDE Connect](https://kdeconnect.kde.org/).

In both cases, there is the note as itself, a file or set of files that is stored somewhere. If you go for proprietary solutions such a Google Keep, you won't even notice the file format. And there is the app to edit the file. Don't focus too much on the app, it doesn't need to be multiplatform if your aim is just to shared notes between devices ;-)

So, per your comment, let me make a suggestion a bit more accurate and arbitrary...
If you don't have one already, you can set up a Nextcloud account at one of the [Nextcloud providers](https://nextcloud.com/signup/) (you can click on "Change provider" to see the full list).
Synchronize your Nextcloud on both your phone and PC with the [Nextcloud clients](https://nextcloud.com/install/#install-clients).
Then on your phone, you can use the [Nextcloud Notes app](https://github.com/stefan-niedermann/nextcloud-notes) to edit your notes. That will be your direct icon app.
On your computer, you only have to edit text files in the `<your-synchronized-nextcloud-folder>/Notes` path. Any text editor can make it. I like [QOwnNotes](https://www.qownnotes.org/) for this purpose (in your case, you would have to tell QOwnNotes to use `<your-synchronized-nextcloud-folder>/Notes` as folder path), but Joplin or even Gedit can make the job too.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you. The scenario is that my PC is huge and the attic is the only place I have space to have it set up until I sort my new bed, so it's in a location that I can't spend much time in. My solution is that I do my research on my phone, find links, instructions and scripts and have everything ready for when I'm at my PC so I'm not rushing and making mistakes.  The PC is old, so bluetooth isn't an option. For convenience I'd like a cloud or drive that has an app icon on both platforms so I don't have to go through my browser.

Comment: I've tried to add a suggestion that I think would fit your need :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [Simplenote](https://simplenote.com/) ? It has Web, Linux, Windows, Mac, Android, and iOS support.

Pretty simple interface with a minimal useful feature sets-

- Plain Text
- Markdown support
- Checklist
- Tagging

It is from the makers of WordPress (Automattic) and is open source([Github](https://github.com/Automattic)).

[image: Supported Platforms]